# How to Solve the Access Array using Lists

Tags: java, arrays, list, data-structures

```
class Result {

      public static int diagonalDifference(List<List<Integer>> arr) {

     int sum_a = 0;
     int sum_b = 0;
     int sum_c = 0;

     int n = 3;



     for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < n; j++,i++){

             sum_a += arr[i][j];
        }
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < n ; i++){
        for(int j = n-1; j >= 0; j--,i++){

            sum_b += arr[i][j]; 
        }
    }

      return sum_c = sum_a + sum_b;

     }

}

public class Solution {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
       BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(System.getenv("OUTPUT_PATH")));

        int n = Integer.parseInt(bufferedReader.readLine().trim());

        List<List<Integer>> arr = new ArrayList<>();

        IntStream.range(0, n).forEach(i -> {
            try {
                arr.add(
                    Stream.of(bufferedReader.readLine().replaceAll("\\s+$", "").split(" "))
                        .map(Integer::parseInt)
                        .collect(toList())
                );
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                throw new RuntimeException(ex);
            }
        });

        int result = Result.diagonalDifference(arr);

        bufferedWriter.write(String.valueOf(result));
        bufferedWriter.newLine();

        bufferedReader.close();
        bufferedWriter.close();
    }
}
```

**I have used two Integer variable to add the diagonal sums from the array. And I get a compile time error.
Solution.java:38: error: array required, but List> found
             sum_a += arr[i][j];

Solution.java:45: error: array required, but List> found
            sum_b += arr[i][j]; 
Can someone help me figure this out.**

Comment: You don't use brackets to access elements of the list, you use 'get' method: `arr.get(i).get(j)`

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by other answers, you should use `get` to access the list elements. What is more important, though, is that you should modify your algorithm. Just a single loop is required, not two loops to sum the diagonal:

```
for(int i = 0; i < arr.size(); i++) {
  sum_a += arr.get(i).get(i);
}
```

and similar for `sum_b`. You can even calculate the difference like this:

```
public static int diagonalDifference(List<List<Integer>> arr) {
   int result = 0;
   for (int i = 0; i < arr.size(); i++) {
      List<Integer> row = arr.get(i);
      result += row.get(i) - row.get(n - i - 1);
   }
   return result;
}
```

Here I suppose that you really want to calculate the difference of the diagonals, not the sum.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    public static int diagonalDifference(List<List<Integer>> arr) {
        int sum_a = 0;
        int sum_b = 0;
        int sum_c = 0;

        int n = 3;

        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < n; j++,i++){
                sum_a += arr.get(i).get(j);
            }
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < n ; i++){
            for(int j = n-1; j >= 0; j--,i++){
                sum_b += arr.get(i).get(j);
            }
        }
        return sum_c = sum_a + sum_b;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
diagonalDifference(List<List<Integer>> arr)
...
sum_a += arr[i][j];
```

You cannot access an ArrayList with [x], you have to use .get(x)

```
diagonalDifference(List<List<Integer>> arr)
...
sum_a += arr.get(i).get(j);
```